# Vista not allowing VB or PHP to connect via SSL

Tags: php, vb.net, ssl, soap, windows-vista

I have two applications (one PHP and one VB) that connect through SSL to REST and SOAP services on an Apache server.  These two applications worked fine under Windows XP, but now that the workstation has been upgraded to Vista they can't connect.

The VB application tries to post data to a REST service and hits an error of:

*The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.*

The PHP application tries to make a SOAP connection via SSL and hits and error of:

*Could not connect to host.*

Both apps work if I use HTTP instead of HTTPS.  Both Chrome and IE can connect through HTTPS/SSL with NO certificate errors to the Apache server/website.  I have even imported the certificate into Vista via IE.

Since there are two different applications using different languages having the same common issue, I believe it has to do with something in the OS.  But what??

Comment: Its a longshot, but try and Disable the Firewall and see if that make any difference

Comment: Firewall on Vista is off.  Nothing has changed on the server and there isn't any firewall rules blocking intranet connections.  Nor any rules to block port 80 and 443.